# PyGTK - gtk.TreeViewColumn (instantiate dynamically)

Tags: python, pygtk

need to dynamically instantiate an object of type gtk.TreeViewColumn through a loop `for`, as in this example: http://dpaste.com/hold/789277/

the output of the code above is:

```
tvc_0 = gtk.TreeViewColumn('id', gtk.CellRendererText(), text = 0)
tvc_1 = gtk.TreeViewColumn('Aspecto', gtk.CellRendererText(), text = 1)
tvc_2 = gtk.TreeViewColumn('Impactos', gtk.CellRendererText(), text = 2)
```

I need to transform the `output` of the above strings in `source code`

already tried using getattr, i could not results. could someone help me?

Hugs!
Juliano

Answer (score 0):

On possible solution without using evil exec/eval:

```
tuple_val = (
    ('id', gtk.CellRendererText(), 0),
    ('Aspectos', gtk.CellRendererText(), 1),
    ('Impactos', gtk.CellRendererText(), 2),
)

def tree_view_factory(id, renderer, text):
    return gtk.TreeViewColumn(id, renderer, text=text)

tvc_0, tvc_1, tvc_2 = map(tree_view_factory, tuple_val)
```

Comment: ok, understood, but I need tvc_0, tvc_1, tvc_2 are dynamically instantiated, as in the example below exec. There is a way to do it with lists? the output I need is this:`tvc_0=gtk.TreeViewColumn('id', gtk.CellRendererText(), text=0)`

Comment: Isn't this what you'll get on my solution ?

Comment: From what I understad, what @JulianoC.Gomes is asking is basically how to execute a string containing python code.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [exec](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-exec_stmt) statement to dynamically execute source code from a string.  For example:

```
exec """
    tvc_0 = gtk.TreeViewColumn('id', gtk.CellRendererText(), text = 0)
    tvc_1 = gtk.TreeViewColumn('Aspecto', gtk.CellRendererText(), text = 1)
    tvc_2 = gtk.TreeViewColumn('Impactos', gtk.CellRendererText(), text = 2)
"""
```

Or in the script you linked:

```
dic = {'0':'id',  '1':'Aspecto',  '2':'Impacto'}
for coluna in range(0, len(dic.keys())):
    exec "tvc_"+str(coluna)+"=gtk.TreeViewColumn('"+dic[str(coluna)]+"', gtk.CellRendererText(), text="+str(coluna)+")"
```

But **be careful**, the execution of arbitrary code strings could lead to serious security problems.

Comment: Helo, what type of security problems we are talking about?
Best Regards!
Juliano

Comment: if you execute arbitrary code from an input string. Some malicious input can execute code in your application. More information here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection